# Unable to activate solution in another machine

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, deployment, solution-package

I have a solution that has custom site columns and content types. When I try to activate this on the production box is does not allow me to do so and whenever I try to activate, it gives me an error which says -

> A duplicate field name "XXXXXXXXXXX" was found.

Although there is no such field with this id in my solution. It is really difficult to troubleshoot. Please help.

Comment: It might not be in your solution, but it is saying it already exists on the site. What did you call this site column you are trying to create? Does it already exist in the site column gallery?

Comment: I have checked this and none of the columns of my solution are present on the site. What might be the reason of the issue?